# Order by logic for notes forum

Tags: mysql

I created a notes section for my site which acts similar to a one-table forum. I have only 1 table with 6 fields: ID (primary ID), Parent (which references the ID it is associating with), Employee_ID, Note, Peer_Name, and Timestamp. A user will go to the site and the page will load all comments left for E_ID. I would like it to display in ID ASC order with any Parent comments under the ID (to show hierarchy). My query needs some help as I can't seem to show the Parent comments to show underneath the main ID.

For example, I have records with:

```
ID Parent Employee_ID, Note,              Peer_Name,   Timestamp
1  NULL   999          note_blahblahblah  Smith, John  2021-10-25 01:00:01
3  1      999          note3_blah_blah    Cody, Jane   2021-10-27 15:00:02
5  NULL   999          note5_blahblah     Doe, Chuck   2021-10-27 16:00:03
7  NULL   999          note7_blahblah     Moe, Mi      2021-10-27 17:00:04
9  7      999          note9_blahblah     Lee, Vic     2021-10-27 18:00:05
```

I need the query to display in order of ID with any Parent rows underneath the respective ID. Parent 4 would go underneath ID 4 and so on. If Parent is NULL, the row does not have any rows underneath.

This query has not worked. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT a.* 
from employee_notes a 
    LEFT JOIN employee_notes b on a.ID = b.Parent 
WHERE a.Employee_ID='999' 
ORDER BY a.ID ASC, b.Parent ASC, a.Timestamp ASC
```

Comment: You need to use `UNION` to make the parents separate rows.

Comment: If I just use JOIN, the rows with NULL with disappear.

Comment: `JOIN` puts the parent on the same row as the child.

Comment: @Barmar your solution of using union did not provide the correct results.  ID column is in ASC order but Parent does not list under the corresponding ID. Continued assistance is requested.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee_notes
WHERE employee_id = '999'
ORDER BY IF(parent IS NULL, ID, parent), parent IS NULL DESC, timestamp
```

The first ordering puts the parent together with all their children, the second ordering puts the parent before the children within that group. Then the children are ordered by timestamp.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dae13d/4)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood and put the parent first.

Comment: Hooray! Thanks @Barmar, your solution worked. many thanks.

Comment: it appears the query submitted is still missing something. I added some data to your fiddle to more clearly illustrate. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1db2f/2  I should see ID's in this order for the first 4 rows as they all reference ID 1. Order should be 1, 3, 9, 10. In your query, it only shows 3, 9, 10.

Comment: You said the parent should be AFTER children. So it's 3, 9, 10, 1.

Comment: If you want parent first, change to `parent IS NULL DESC`

Comment: That's what I had first, but you said it was wrong so I changed it.

Comment: My apologies. Your last clue works. If you can, edit your query so I can approve it. You have been very helpful. Much appreciated.